# removeNodeAfter method explanation

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

this is a method to remove a current selected node in the linked list. What i don't get is link.link part. Isn't ".link" a method? There is no link method written in the class yet it still works. Can someone explain why?

```
public void removeNodeAfter( )   
{
  link = link.link;
}
```

Full class can be found at https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/edu/colorado/nodes/IntNode.java

Answer (score 0):

Look at the top of the class, where you can find the definition of `link` as `private IntNode link;`. It's an *attribute* or *instance variable*.